# TV show about a boy who finds a hidden room

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, soft-sci-fi

TV show about a boy who finds a hidden room with goblin and finds out what he is and has kid with alien in another dimension or something. Time moves fast in that place and his friends try to get him out and when they do he returns back to when he was young and his child never existed and alien came out to sad and mad.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it was made? Also, was this live-action or animated?

Comment: This description was hard to interpret, so I'm not sure what you meant on a couple of points. For example, when you say that the boy "finds out what he is," do you mean that he finds out he's an alien? Also, what did you mean by "alien came out to sad and mad"?

Comment: "has kid with alien" did the boy have a kid with an alien? As in they mated? Which one carried?

Comment: Where that hidden room was located? In some house? Living quarters?